# Org Babel doesn't load Graphviz editing mode for dot sources

Tags: emacs, graphviz, org-mode

```
#+begin_src dot :file diagram.png
<some diagram code>
#+end_src
```

When I <kbd>C-c '</kbd> on this block, the content opens in Fundamental mode (but I have Graphviz mode installed). How do I tell Org / Babel to use that mode?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I understand the problem lies with the major-mode name.
I solved the issue with the following line of code:

```
(add-to-list 'org-src-lang-modes (quote ("dot" . graphviz-dot)))
```